# preventDefault not working on form loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm inserting a form into my page with AJAX, then I want to submit this form also with AJAX, so I use `event.preventDefault` to stop the submit button from making a POST request. However, no matter what I try, I cannot stop the submit button's default behavior unless I use `return false;`. Why?

I'm also using DOM event delegation.

<s>**EDIT:** Updated the code to add parenthesis after `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, this is not the issue!</s>

**EDIT2:** Nevermind, I'm stupid. You guys were right, it *was* not adding parenthesis to `preventDefault`. I just realised I added them inside the wrong function. Updated my code to show it without parentheses, as it was originally. Sorry!

---

**Initial HTML**

```
<button id="add-form-button" type="button">Add Form</button>

<div id="form-container"></div>
```

**jQuery that adds new form**

```
$('#add-form-button').on('click', function() {
    // AJAX returns response
    $('#form-container').html(response);
});
```

**HTML after adding form**

```
<button id="add-form-button" type="button">Add Form</button>

<div id="form-container">
    <form id="my-form" action="form-action.php" method="post">
        <textarea name="my-textarea"></textarea>    
        <button id="submit-form" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery to submit form**

```
// This doesn't work
$('#form-container').on('click', '#submit-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    event.stopPropagation; // <-- added this to test
    // Page goes to form-action.php even though it shouldn't
});

// This doesn't work either
$('#form-container').on('submit', '#my-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;    
    event.stopPropagation; // <-- added this to test
    // Page goes to form-action.php even though it shouldn't
});
```

**jQuery that DOES work, but no clue why**

```
// This works but it doesn't make sense that preventDefault doesn't work.
$('#form-container').on('click', '#submit-form', function(event) {
    return false;
});
```

Can someone please explain why `preventDefault` doesn't work in this instance, but `return false;` does work?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Did you check the console for errors

Comment: Those things _should_ work.  If it isn't working then something else is interfering.  Maybe there is a binding somewhere else that is causing the actual submit.

Comment: @adeneo The page gets automatically redirected so I can't check the console for errors.

Comment: @nurdyguy I think this may actually be the case. Is there any way to check if there are other bindings connected to this button?

Comment: @Swen, Dev Tools > Event Listeners.

Comment: or, dev tools -> hamburger button -> preserve logs

Comment: You guys were right, updated my original question. Deeply ashamed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` as if they were properties, rather than methods:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Adding the parentheses will invoke them.

**EDIT** (since you fixed the parens issue in your code):

Delegate the listener to `document`, `submit` will not trigger for the element you have selected (in certain browsers and versions of jQuery).

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my-form', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
)};
```

Or, *ideally*, attach the `submit` listener to `#my-form` after it is created. This way the `submit` event will show up under the **Event listeners** in your Dev Tools.

Comment: @Swen, see my update.

Comment: the update shouldn't make a difference in it working or not. the form-container is static, so it should be fine.

Comment: @KevinB, `div`s do not trigger `submit` events.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen in jquery's made up event system, it can if it's delegated. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Pretty sure the submit event bubbles natively too, other than in IE8.

Comment: See updated question, you guys were right about the parenthesis.

Comment: @Swen, does that mean it is working?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Isn't the first, or last time I spend 2 hours figuring why something isn't working, only to realise it was a stupid mistake!

Comment: @Swen, in that case you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 things going on here. First, you are not calling the functions properly. You are missing the parentheses:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

Second, you need to handle the `submit` event of the `form`, and `preventDefault()` on that event. The way you are handling that now is that you are handling the `submit` event of the form container (`#form-container`). `Div`'s do not have a `submit` event to be handled. You need to handle the `submit` event of `#my-form`:

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();    
)};
```

Third, you are creating a form dynamically, so the order you do things is important. **You must wire up your `submit` event handler AFTER you create the form**. The tricky thing here is that because you are adding html, it might take a few milli-seconds for the form to actually be rendered in the DOM. So I would delay that task by half a second or so:

```
$('#add-form-button').on('click', function() {
    // AJAX returns response
    $('#form-container').html(response);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#my-form').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();    
        )};
    } ,400);
});
```

Comment: that... won't work on a dynamically added form.

Comment: @KevinB, it _could_, if called after the form is created.

Comment: @KevinB, good point. I have edited to handle that appropriately.

Comment: I'm.... Stupid. See the update in the original question.